# Running 'ionic serve' in ionic web apps in Visual Studio when building a project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Coming from developing Angular 2 I started learning Ionic. And when setting up the development environment, I came across some issues:

What I did was creating a new empty web project using Visual Studio, then copied the files (except for node_modules) to the project directory then included them in Visual Studio.

Now, when running `npm install` I get `npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\[MyUsername]\source\repos\Ionic\package.json'`

What I did to solve this error was to `cd` to the project's folder then ruining `npm install`, but I still don't know why it couldn't find the `pacjakge.json` file.

Now my issue is when doing a build with Visual Studio, nothing changes. Is there a was to configure maybe Visual Studio or my Ionic app so that when doing a build, it would compile the files and after refreshing the web page, it would display my changes?